# C# get Linq Table from generic

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, linq-to-sql

I have this repeating method in my classes (some lines have been removed to simplify the question):

```
public void CreateNew(DBContext db, SystemMessageReport newRec)
{
    db.SystemMessageReports.InsertOnSubmit(newRec);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to move this method to it's parent class as a generic method.

If `SystemMessageReport` is passed as `T`, is it possible to `InsertOnSubmit` to it's correspdonding `Linq Table`?  For example:

```
public void CreateNew<T>(DBContext db, T newRec)
{
    db.T.InsertOnSubmit(newRec);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
public void CreateNew(DBContext db, T newRec)
{
    db.GetTable(typeof(T)).InsertOnSubmit(newRec);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Should it be `CreateNew<T>` maybe?